# Take value from object if key exists otherwise take value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there an operator in javascript that will extract my `props` value if exists, if props not exist that will extract `rowData[key]`?

Example:
`rowData[key].props`

if props exists = `rowData[key].props`

if props not exists = `rowData[key]`

Comment: *"if props exists*" Do you mean if `props` key exists OR if `props` has a value other than null / undefined?

Comment: [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: As this seems unclear as to possible values, since there is no sample data, I would suggest the following which should account for `undefined` and `null` (falsy) values for `rowData[key]`: `rowData.hasOwnProperty("key") && rowData["key"].hasOwnProperty("props") ? rowData["key"].props : rowData["key"] || {};`

Answer (score 1):

null coalesce will do this

```
const result = rowData[key].props ?? rowData[key];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator

```
let value_you_want = rowData[key]?.props ? rowData[key].props : rowData[key]
```

Comment: What if `props` is just falsy?

Comment: @Lain In that case the condition will ```rowData[key]?.props``` will be false and go to the else part